# How to load the localized nib?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have localized my nib files, I've got both English and Polish version:

[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/70/postitappdelegatemtwitt.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/70/postitappdelegatemtwitt.png)

In my code I load the nib:

```
newPostUIViewController = [[NewPostUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewPostView" bundle:nil];
```

Unfortunately when I run my app in Polish mode I still see the English version of the UI.
Do I need to do something more to make my app display the Polish version of the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
Menu Build->Clean All Targets made the trick.